# Python crashing when executing keras fit_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train a dataset using keras/tensorflow on python 3.7 using spyder.

The kernel keeps crashing in the first epoch when executing the following code:

```
classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                     steps_per_epoch = 8000,
                     epochs = 25,
                     validation_data = test_set,
                     validation_steps = 2000)
```

What can I do?

Please find below an exerpt of the crash report of python.

```
Process:               python3.7 [22322]
Path:                  /Volumes/VOLUME/anaconda3/*/python
Identifier:            python3.7
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        python [21748]
Responsible:           python3.7 [22322]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2019-12-30 18:05:13.068 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G2022)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     4.2 (17P2551)
Anonymous UUID:        2A20C189-D904-384B-379F-BE5612A1524C

Sleep/Wake UUID:       C9CD6FAD-CFF6-4AA6-A077-0FE34F472129

Time Awake Since Boot: 240000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1400 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  ZMQbg/1

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: ZMQbg/1
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7672d2c2 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff766976a6 abort + 127
2   libiomp5.dylib                  0x0000000142ca37e3 __kmp_abort_process + 35

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7672d78a kevent + 10
1   libzmq.5.dylib                  0x000000011701e6df thread_routine(void*) + 63
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff767e62eb _pthread_body + 126
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff767e9249 _pthread_start + 66
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff767e540d thread_start + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7672d78a kevent + 10
1   libzmq.5.dylib                  0x000000011701e6df thread_routine(void*) + 63
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff767e62eb _pthread_body + 126
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff767e9249 _pthread_start + 66
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff767e540d thread_start + 13
```

Comment: It's not letting me post the crash report of python ( too long)

Comment: How many images are there in ```training_set```? ```steps_per_epoch```  should be ```train_length // batch_size``` maybe try increasing steps per epoch?

Comment: 8000 images in training_set. Increasing steps_per_epoch doesnt seem to help. It seems like the kernel is crashing before starting with 1st epoch (terminal shows "Epoch 1/25" but no progress indication)